# sort groupby column descending

Tags: python, pandas

```
sample = pd.DataFrame({'Cat':['A','B','C','A','B','C','A','B','C'], 
                       'Year':[2001,2002,2003,2001,2002,2003,2001,2002,2003]})

for s in sample.groupby(['Year']):
    print s[0]
```

That would give

```
2001
2002
2003
```

How do I sort the groupby results in descending order to get ..

```
2003
2002
2001
```

Comment: @EdChum I get `Type Error: 'bool' object is not callable` when I do that

Comment: Sorry error in my suggestion, will delete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your best bet would be to sort the frame descending ahead of time, and pass `sort=False` to the groupby operation so the data isn't re-sorted.

```
In [78]: sample = sample.sort(['Year'], ascending=False)

In [79]: for s in sample.groupby(['Year'], sort=False):
    ...:     print s[0]
    ...:     
2003
2002
2001
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort a pandas dataframe in ascending vs. descending order like this:

```
result = df.sort(['Year'], ascending=0 )
```

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort.html

Comment: I get a `KeyError` when I try `reversed`

Comment: Whoops, my bad. I overlooked that. Edited.